# When combining xml, the problem of repetition in xml when I use a theme

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

my xslt document, i didn't add it because my XML extensions are too many, if you want I can add them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="//Products/Product/Combinations/Combination">
    <Products>
            <Product>
                <xsl:element name="modelcode">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../@ModelCode"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="color">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../Color/@value"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="brand">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../Brand/@value"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="sku">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Sku"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="size">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </Product>

        <xsl:call-template name="listele">
            <xsl:with-param name="doc" select="document('try2.xml')//Products/Product/Combinations/Combination"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

        <xsl:call-template name="listele">
            <xsl:with-param name="doc" select="document('try3.xml')//Products/Product/Combinations/Combination"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

    </Products>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="listele">
    <xsl:param name="doc"/>
    <Product>
        <xsl:element name="modelcode">
            <xsl:value-of select="../../@ModelCode"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="color">
            <xsl:value-of select="../../Color/@value"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="brand">
            <xsl:value-of select="../../Brand/@value"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="sku">
            <xsl:value-of select="Sku"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="size">
            <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </Product>
</xsl:template>
```

every xml is repeated on output

```
<Products>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIS</sku>
    <size>S</size>
</Product>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIS</sku>
    <size>S</size>
</Product>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIS</sku>
    <size>S</size>
</Product>
</Products>
<Products>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIM</sku>
    <size>M</size>
</Product>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIM</sku>
    <size>M</size>
</Product>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIM</sku>
    <size>M</size>
</Product>
</Products>
<Products>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIL</sku>
    <size>L</size>
</Product>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIL</sku>
    <size>L</size>
</Product>
<Product>
    <modelcode>M1</modelcode>
    <color>haki</color>
    <brand>TRY</brand>
    <sku>M1HAKIL</sku>
    <size>L</size>
</Product>
</Products>
<Products>9variant(27sku) copy for 3variant(9sku)</Products>
<Products>9variant(27sku) copy for 3variant(9sku)</Products>
   .
   .
   .
```

i need

```
<Products>
     <Product>
          first xml nodes
     </Product>
     <Product>
          second xml nodes
     </Product>
     <Product>
          thirth xml nodes
     </Product>
</Products>
```

I tried using foreach in the template, the result is the same.
I don't have a problem if I don't use a theme, but I have 300 xml and there's a lot of code repetition.

Comment: You need to provide your input XML to complete a [mcve] making this question answerable. If this seems to be too much, you have to restrict the XML to the _absolute minimum_ required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: XSLT has no "themes", so it's difficult to understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a named template with a `doc` parameter does not change the context to the document referenced in the parameter. In your XSLT, the template named `listele` operates in the same context as the template that called it - i.e. the `//Products/Product/Combinations/Combination` element of the input XML. Therefore each call retrieves the same values, from the same location.

If you want the template to retrieve values from the document referenced in the `doc` parameter, you must include the document in the requested path; instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Sku"/>
```

you need to have something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$doc/Sku"/>
```